# How to update a value in database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to update a value at my database.
To do so I have some code:

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'host',
            user: 'admin',
            password: 'pass',
            database: 'db'
        });
        // connect to database
        connection.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return err;
            }
            connection.query('UPDATE botrequests SET places_count = ? WHERE telegram_id = ?', [places_count - global.count, global.telegram_id],
                function (error, results, fields) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                    res.render('index.pug', {
                        results: results
                    });
                });
        });
```

So I've got a table `botrequests` where I want to update `places_count` value by deducting `global.count` if `telegram_id` is equal to `global.telegram_id`

As an error I get

```
C:\Users\lesha\Desktop\pugbot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

ReferenceError: places_count is not defined
```

However `places_count` is sure in the table. What's wrong about my code?

Comment: Right, but it's not defined in your JavaScript which is what you're trying to access.

Comment: Retrieve your `places_count` value from your DB before you perform the operation.

Comment: Try `UPDATE botrequests SET places_count = places_count - ? WHERE telegram_id = ?` and remove `places_count` from your array.

Answer (score 2):

`places_count` is not a variable in your execution context.

Try:

```
connection.query('UPDATE botrequests SET places_count = places_count - ? WHERE telegram_id = ?', [global.count, global.telegram_id], ...)
```

Comment: hahahaha super fast... by the time I finished writing an answer yours were already here and you even commented it first lol! +1

Comment: @JorgeCampos that does not work as it should. How can I use in this reqest the current field (places_count) value to operate with it?

Comment: @Alex Please explain in more detail what you mean.  If you want the current value before you increment, you will have to fetch the value first.

Comment: @Alex your code is pretty straight forward, if you want to just calculate it as it is stated this answer is all you need. If you need anything else with that field you have to explain it on your question. Because right now nothing in your question points the need of that field other than that calculation